# Which optimization metric for differenced data when doing a multi-step forecast?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I've written an LSTM in Keras for univariate time series forecasting.  I'm using an input window of size 48 and an output window of size 12, i.e. I'm predicting 12 steps at once.  This is working generally well with an optimization metric such as RMSE.

For non-stationary time series I'm differencing the data before feeding the data to the LSTM.  Then after predicting, I take the inverse difference of the predictions.

When differencing, RMSE is not suitable as an optimization metric as the earlier prediction steps are a lot more important than later steps.  When we do the inverse difference after creating a 12-step forecast, then the earlier (differenced) prediction steps are going to affect the inverse difference of later steps.

So what I think I need is an optimization metric that gives the early prediction steps more weight, preferably exponentially.

Does such a metric exist already or should I write my own?  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: "When differencing, RMSE is not suitable as an optimization metric as the earlier prediction steps are a lot more important than later steps. " Where did you get this from? If anything it should be the opposite: The whole point of differencing is to stabilize the variance of the series.

Comment: When you apply the inverse difference, the de-differenced value of later predictions depends on what the differenced value of earlier predictions was.  E.g. if the differenced predictions (1st order) are 3, -2, 4 then (if the baseline was zero) the de-differenced outcome is 3, 1, 5.  

If we would have predicted the first value seriously wrong then that would affect later predictions as well.  E.g. if we had predicted 6, -2, 4 then the de-differenced outcome would be 6, 4, 8.  So mispredicting early values on differenced data also affects later predictions after inverse differencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrote my own optimization metric, it seems to work well, certainly better than RMSE.

Still curious what's the best practice here.  I'm relatively new to forecasting.

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def weighted_rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    weights = K.arange(start=y_pred.get_shape()[1], stop=0, step=-1, dtype='float32')
    y_true_w = y_true * weights
    y_pred_w = y_pred * weights
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_true_w - y_pred_w), axis=-1))
```